# Compare time in perl using subroutine

Tags: perl

I found the script to compare the time and get the return value. But that script not validating the following scenario properly. Please help me on this.

Script Path : http://perlprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/10/perl-function-to-compare-two-dates.html#recent

```
Input : 2015-07-01 00:50:00,2015-07-01 00:00:00, returns : 0
```

Comment: Please don't use that site to learn how to code Perl, that is the worst example of a tutorial I've seen in years!  (It's not only buggy, but it also doesn't use best practices like `use strict;` and `use warnings`; it uses prototypes (`($$)`) which you shouldn't do unless you know exactly what you're doing, and as choroba mentions, it's unnecessary code, you can simply use `$date1 cmp $date2`.)

Comment: @mscha: It also declares variables in a block at the top of the code, uses `split / /` instead of `split ' '` and uses overly-long variable names that try to express the type of the data when Perl isn't typed like that and has `$`, `@`, `%` etc. anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code

from

```
push(@marr_date1,split(/-/, $mstr_onlytime1));
push(@marr_date2,split(/-/, $mstr_onlytime2));
```

to

```
push( @marr_date2, split( /[-:]/, $mstr_onlydate2 ) );
push( @marr_date2, split( /[-:]/, $mstr_onlytime2 ) );
```

It works for me.:)

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug in the tutorial: it splits time on `-`, not `:` (even if they use `:` in the example).

You don't need the function at all, though. Dates in this format could be compared by the standard `cmp` operator.